# Get a list of all mesh vertices that have a non-zero vertex group value in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

How do I get a list of all mesh vertices that have a non-zero vertex group value in Animation Nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Vertex Group Input* node can be used as a mask in the *Mask List Node* to only return vertices locations of those vertices that have non zero vertex group values:

[image: Node Tree]